Real Life Applications of Two-Variable Quadratic Formulas
Where do two-variable quadratic formulas show up today as real-life combinatorial complexity challenges? Weather? Particle motion? Celestial calculations? Routing? Does anyone have specific examples? I'm interested in learning about how a theoretical constant time or sublinear solution to two-variable quadratic formulas could apply to real life by improving the current state of computational complexity and decidability.
I am motivated by the paper linked below where the NP-Complete number theory problem is the two-variable quadratics of the form αx2 + βy − γ = 0; α, β, γ ϵ ω, with solutions in natural numbers and x of x2 = α modulo β; α, β, ξ ϵ ω, without factorization of β.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000078900442
Thank you!
